# Can't get content of text file from internet server using Java

Tags: javascript, java

The file is located at: http://japgrammartest.freevnn.com/Chuong2.txt

This is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://japgrammartest.freevnn.com/Chuong2.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

When I call the `in.readLine()`, it returns:

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

But it works fine with other sites. How can I fix this?

Comment: as the message says, you need to enable javascript in your browser

Answer (score 2):

You can use htmlunit for that

```
String content = ((TextPage) new WebClient().
getPage("http://japgrammartest.freevnn.com/Chuong2.txt"))
.getContent();
```

you can get htmlunit from maven repository with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you view source code using the below link...everything would be clear.

view-source:http://japgrammartest.freevnn.com/Chuong2.txt

They have encrypted the page and when you call using broswer they call toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+ nethod to decrypt back.But as you are running in your java code, javascript file is missing and hence the error.

Comment: So is there anything I can do with my site to fix that?